# Interpolating a huge set of data

Tags: excel, interpolation

So I have a very large set of data (4 million rows+) with journey times between two location nodes for two separate years (2015 and 2024). These are stored in dat files in a format of:

| Node A | Node B | Journey Time (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 124 | 51.4 |

So I have one long file of over 4 million rows for each year. I need to interpolate journey times for a year between the two for which I have data. I've tried Power Query in Excel as well as Power BI Desktop but have had no reasonable solution beyond cutting the files into smaller < 1 million row pieces so that Excel can manage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Python.........?

Comment: an actual database?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What type of output are you looking for?  PowerBI can easily handle this amount of data, but it depends what you expect your result to be.  If you're looking for the average % change in node to node travel time between the two years, then PowerBI could be utilised as it is great at aggregating and comparing large datasets.

However, if you are wanting an output of every single node to node delta between those two years i.e. 4M row output, then PowerBI will calculate this, but then what do you do with it.... a 4M long table?

If you're looking to have an exported result >150K rows (PowerBI limit) or >1M rows (Excel limit), then I would use Python for that (as mentioned above)

Comment: Sadly I need it in that huge 4M long format. I have data for all these node connections' journey times in 2015 and (modelled) 2024. I want to extract interpolated values for all these node connections for 2019.